# Why AMD Ryzen 3700x 8 cores utilizes only up to 10% CPU on Visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2019

I recently changed my CPU to AMD Ryzen 3700X 8 cores and motherboard to B450 TOMAHAWK MAX MS-7C02.

**The problem: Visual studio utilizes only up to 5-10% CPU.**

What I tried:

- Changing parameters in BIOS(Changed base frequency, turned of Cool'n'Quiet)
- Turned off power saving mode in Control Panel settings
- Tried CPU on "stress" software (HeavyLoad) - CPU runs 100% there.

I tried to search for similar cases and solutions, but I couldn't find anything related to a problem like that. It really bugs me and I'm not sure why such problem could occur.

Any help is welcome and very appreciated!

Comment: 8 core and SMT means 16 cores. 100% cpu usage / 16 cores mean 6,25. So 1 core is busy doing some stuff, the other 15 are idle. some operations of vs2019 maybe are single threaded and can't use more threads.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that Visual Studio is doing something that is not multithreaded and is therefore only using one core instead of all 8 cores.

Are you compiling code in VS?  If so, there may be a VS setting to make the compiler use multiple threads.